# React Native wrapper, the ios sdk is included in that, but that is not accessible in package

Tags: ios, react-native, sdk

I have including a native ios sdk, in my react native project. I am doing the integration of ios sdk by react native wrapper. For that I have made a react native wrapper. In that I am able to call a method of react native and have result by callback in react native code. `But in my wrapper's RNTapPayment.m file I am not able to import sdk. Xcode gives error.`

But the sdk can be imported in react-native main ios folder's AppDelegate.m file.

In my react native wrapper:

```c
    //RNTapPayment.m

    #import "RNTapPayment.h"
    #import <React/RCTLog.h>
    #import <React/RCTConvert.h>

    @import goSellSDK; // my sdk
     // Error in above line: Module 'goSellSDK' not found

    @implementation RNTapPayment

    - (dispatch_queue_t)methodQueue
   {
         return dispatch_get_main_queue();
    }
    RCT_EXPORT_MODULE(TapPayment)

    RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(openTapPaymentUI:(NSDictionary *)details callback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)
    {
      NSString *SecretAPIkey = [RCTConvert 
    NSString:details[@"SecretAPIkey"]];
      NSString *AppID = [RCTConvert NSString:details[@"AppID"]];
      RCTLogInfo(@"Pretending to create an event %@ and %@", AppID, SecretAPIkey);

      callback(@[[NSNull null], AppID]);
    }

    @end
```

error: Module 'goSellSDK' not found